# send message from my web page (client) to a pc (server)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, udp

i would like to send message from my web page (client) to a pc 
Problem comes in when I try to send data. It complains about this line:            m_socWorker.Send(byData);  Error Message is Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
here is my code

```
 // Counts the pings
private int pingsSent;
// Can be used to notify when the operation completes
AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
public static Socket m_socWorker;
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex != null)
    {
        // Reset the number of pings
        pingsSent = 0;
        // Clear the textbox of any previous content
        TextBox2.Dispose();
        TextBox2.Text += "Pinging " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + " with 32 bytes of data:\r\n\r\n";
        // Send the ping
        Thread thd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendPing));
        thd.Start();
        //SendPing();
        try
        {

            UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient();

            IPAddress remotipadd = IPAddress.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            udpclient.Connect(remotipadd,10001);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint senderip = new IPEndPoint(remotipadd, Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue));

            udpclient.Connect(senderip);
            TextBox2.Text += "Connect";
           // listbox1.Items.Add("connected");



        }
        catch (SocketException s)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s.Message);
        }


    }

}
private void SendPing()
{
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pingSender = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();

    // Create an event handler for ping complete
    pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(pingSender_Complete);

    // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
    byte[] packetData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("................................");

    // Jump though 50 routing nodes tops, and don't fragment the packet
    PingOptions packetOptions = new PingOptions(50, true);

    // Send the ping asynchronously

    pingSender.SendAsync(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, 5000, packetData, packetOptions, resetEvent);

}

private void pingSender_Complete(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user.
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        TextBox2.Text += "Ping was canceled...\r\n";

        // The main thread can resume
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        TextBox2.Text += "An error occured: " + e.Error + "\r\n";

        // The main thread can resume
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }
    else
    {
        PingReply pingResponse = e.Reply;
        // Call the method that displays the ping results, and pass the information with it
        ShowPingResults(pingResponse);
    }
}

public void ShowPingResults(PingReply pingResponse)
{
    if (pingResponse == null)
    {
        // We got no response
        TextBox2.Text += "There was no response.\r\n\r\n";
        return;
    }
    else if (pingResponse.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        // We got a response, let's see the statistics
        TextBox2.Text += "Reply from " + pingResponse.Address.ToString() + ": bytes=" + pingResponse.Buffer.Length + " time=" + pingResponse.RoundtripTime + " TTL=" + pingResponse.Options.Ttl + "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        // The packet didn't get back as expected, explain why
        TextBox2.Text += "Ping was unsuccessful: " + pingResponse.Status + "\r\n\r\n";
    }
    // Increase the counter so that we can keep track of the pings sent
    pingsSent++;
    // Send 4 pings
    if (pingsSent < 4)
    {
        SendPing();
    }
}


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        Object objData = TextBox2.Text;
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
        //Session["m_socWorker"] = m_socWorker;
        //m_socWorker = (Socket) Session["m_socWorker"];
        m_socWorker.Send(byData);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use your debugger to find out what's null? Given that, have you worked backwards to figure out *why* it's null? You haven't included enough code for us to really help you. These problems are most easily solved by stepping through your code which we can't do.

Comment: yeah m_socworker is what is null 
shall i put server and client code ?

Comment: Where is m_socWorker assigned? You must assign it to something.

Comment: m_socWorker  is an object of socket 
 public static Socket m_socWorker;

Comment: That does not answer my question. That is a declaration, not an assignment. There should be, somewhere, something like `m_socWorker = new Socket(...);`

Comment: in deed i've tried so but when i do so an error is invoked saying that socket dose not take zero argument ?

Comment: Look at the documentation for [System.Net.Sockets.Socket constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Indeed, the constructor does not take 0 arguments.